# How do I get Thunderbird not to store emails on the remote server when using IMAP?

Tags: thunderbird, imap

I'm using thunderbird with an IMAP account. What I want is for Thunderbird to connect, download and then delete the downloaded emails from the IMAP server. I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how IMAP works. If you want the messages downloaded and deleted then you should be using POP instead.

Comment: I thought this was a Thunderbird setting..?

Comment: Thunderbird may allow you to *download and cache* IMAP messages on the local system, but in the end the messages exist on the IMAP server.

Comment: Bah, I could write a mail client that'd download messages locally and immediately delete them from the server. Thunderbird is a mail client.. Someone wrote it.. ... COGNITION ERROR. SKYNET SHUTTING DOWN.

Comment: Of course you could. But why would you, when POP exists for that.

Comment: my mail provider has no pop access. Is there a make shift solution? I'm mostly worried about disk space.

Comment: Create a mailbox on your local system and move messages there.

Comment: Evidently, you may want to do this because your mail provider doesn't provide pop access  :P

Comment: Igancio, another scenario is when you are reading email from _several_ hosts and it's organized as bunch of folders (Old inbox, Sent-mail, Conference, Important, etc.) In such case it's important to retain the same structure of mail folders.  

Plus to have newest msgs on your server, so every host reading it could sync own local cache to the server (by appending new msgs to the old ones). So every important msg you got in your life can be access whenever/wherever you like.

So POP3 won't help in this case.  Every mail server has it's storage limits. So the solution is still needed.

Answer (score 5):

Move the email from your Thunderbird IMAP Folder to one of your Thunderbird **Local Folders** and then it will be on your hard drive and no longer on the IMAP server. Here's how:
http://en.flossmanuals.net/thunderbird/reading-and-organising-mail/ and scroll to **Move emails from the Inbox to another folder** and make sure you move the email to a sub-folder of **Local Folders** and not to a subfolder of your IMAP account.